# AWS WebSocket API: how can I invoke API Gateway WebSocket URL from nodejs code running in EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I am building my app on AWS and yy app uses websocket like this:

Frontend WebSocket client ---> AWS API Gateway Websocket API ----> Nodejs backend in EC2 instance

While I have figured out the necessary configurations for the above work flow to work (for the client to connect and send message to Nodejs backend), I am having issues with the reverse side:

In the nodejs backend, I need to send a message to the websocket client by calling the API Gateway Websocket API endpoint.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION //Here add you region
});


let WebSocketConnectionIds = StateManager.readFromState('connectionIds');
const connectionId = WebSocketConnectionIds['jack_smith'];
const URL = `https://h123as4.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/production/@connections/${connectionId}`;

const postData = JSON.stringify({'message': 'hello from server!'}) ;

try {
    await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: postData }).promise();
  } catch (e) {

    console.log('apigwManagementApi.postToConnection error: ', e);
  }
```

This is throwing the below error:

```
apigwManagementApi.postToConnection error:  AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::635051002756:assumed-role/my-current-role/i-0c929184c76c88801 is not authorized to perform: execute-api:ManageConnections on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-northeast-1:********2756:h123as4/production/POST/@connections/{connectionId}
    at Object.extractError (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:49:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myapp/api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12) {
  code: 'AccessDeniedException',
  time: 2022-01-20T08:35:56.826Z,
  requestId: '840e7745-805c-4a14-8643-a07d99765d8f',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 64.73772580132132
}
```

So, obviously my EC2 instance has this role `my-current-role`, which is not authorized to invoke the API Gateway WebSocket URL.

How do I grant EC2 instance authority to invoke API Gateway WebSocket APIs?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS access denied error is very descriptive in terms of the missing policy. You need `execute-api:ManageConnections`.

For example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:ManageConnections"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:a123456789/test/POST/mydemoresource/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That said, you may need other permissions for the WebSocket connection to succeed. Should you encounter another access denied error, you can always inspect the error message to find exactly the action needed.